# Counter for main() in Linux OS

Tags: c, linux

i want to implement a counter in Linux which keep a track of how many times
main() is called by any process.

when i start this counter thing as a process, from that time it will tell me how many times main() was called not by my program but in the entire OS system

example:
i start this as a daemon and then i create a simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  //some code
  return 0;
}
```

Now here main is called so the counter will increment by one.

Can anyone explain me how can this be done.?

thanks

Comment: You mean the main of a program you created or any main() function called by the kernel?

Comment: main called by all the programs in userspace not just created by me but even any daemons

Comment: What would be the point? Basically, that's a program call counter. Since basically all programs contain a main as entry point.

Comment: so can i access this program call counter and keep a track of it? do i need to make the changes in kernel source or can be done in userspace??

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at: [Proc connector and socket filters](http://netsplit.com/the-proc-connector-and-socket-filters)

> The Proc Connector and Socket Filters Posted on February 9, 2011 by scott
>
> The proc connector is one of those interesting kernel features that most people rarely come across, and even more rarely find documentation on. Likewise the socket filter. This is a shame, because they’re both really quite useful interfaces that might serve a variety of purposes if they were better documented.
>
> The proc connector allows you to receive notification of process events such fork and exec calls, as well as changes to a process’s uid, gid or sid (session id). These are provided through a socket-based interface by reading instances of struct proc_event defined in the kernel header....

Answer (score 0):

main() is just a abstract code; assembler uses functions' name as a hint, and converts them into numbers. So you can't implement such counter.

main() is usually called once, what you mean may be a program which counts how many programs are executed.

There is `popen` in Linux which performs the given command, and yields the result as FILE *, so you can execute the `ps` command and parse it to get the list of the processes. You can continuously invoke popen and count the number of programs.

```
char Buffer[1024];
sprintf(Buffer,"ps ");
FILE *ptr = popen(Buffer, "r");
if(NULL != ptr)
{
    while(fgets(Buffer, sizeof(Buffer),ptr));
    pclose(ptr);
}
// Now the list of processes are in Buffer
```

Comment: I just want a counter exclusively for this specific function i.e main() . i know it seems useless but i am not interested in the use but instead the implementation of the counter

Comment: I mean, because assembler converts code into machine code and optimizer could change the structure, it is impossible to know where main() exactly is.